# Chai test doesn't pass the cookie authentification middleware

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, chai

I have a middleware that checks if a user is loggued-in before letting him access a route. It looks like this:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const authenticate = (req: Authenticate, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = req.cookies; 
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY, (error, res) => {
      if (error) return res.sendStatus(403);
      req.cookie = { _id: res._id, locale: res.locale };
      return next();
    });
  }
  return res.sendStatus(401);
};

export default authenticate;
```

The test is:

```js
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import { server } from "../index";

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const api = chai.request(server).keepOpen();

describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", () => {
    api
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Cookie", "_id=567;locale=en")
      .end(function (err, res) {
        chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
      });
  });
});
```

The test works fine if I remove the middleware from the route. So:

```js
// OK
router.post("/user/:id", searchUser);

// NOT OK
router.post("/user/:id", authenticate, searchUser);
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendStatus' of undefined
> at /Users/myname/Desktop/Code/myapp/server/src/middleware/authenticate.ts:21:29 at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/Users/myname/Desktop/Code/myapp/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:57:12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` variable of the `jwt.verify()` callback function overwrites the `res` variable of the `authenticate` middleware, which is why you get this error. You should give it a different name to avoid conflicts.

I think you got the `req.cookies` from `chai-http`. If you didn't, you probably forgot to use `cookie-parser` middleware.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import authenticate from './mws/authenticate';

const server = express();

server.use(cookieParser());
server.get('/user/:id', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  res.json({ id, name: 'teresa teng' });
});

export { server };
```

`authenticate.ts`:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const authenticate = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = req.cookies;
  console.log('cookies: ', req.cookies);
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY, (error, verifyResponse) => {
      if (error) return res.sendStatus(403);
      req.cookies = { _id: verifyResponse._id, locale: verifyResponse.locale };
      return next();
    });
  }
  return res.sendStatus(401);
};

export default authenticate;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { server } from './';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const api = chai.request(server).keepOpen();

describe('GET /user/:id', () => {
  it('return user information', (done) => {
    api
      .get('/user/123')
      .set('Cookie', '_id=567;locale=en')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

logs:

```sh
  GET /user/:id
cookies:  { _id: '567', locale: 'en' }
    1) return user information
```